# Unix command to append the content of files in a file list

Tags: file, list, unix, merge, append

I have a list of 102 file locations in a file. I have to merge the contents of each file in the list into a single file.

Inside the file list, each line consists of one file name.

Please help me a find a way to do it in a UNIX environment.

Comment: cat \`echo list-file\` > single-file

Answer (score 2):

This can work:

```
while read file
do
   cat $file >> new_file
done < your_file_with_names
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file1
aaa1
$ cat file2
aaa2
$ cat file3
aaa3
$ cat a
file1
file2
file3
$ while read file; do cat $file >> new_file; done < a
```

Result:

```
$ cat new_file 
aaa1
aaa2
aaa3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in a `for loop`:

```
LISTFILE="/path/to/file/with/list"
RESULTFILE="/path/to/result/file"


if test -f $RESULTFILE; then
  rm $RESULTFILE;
fi

for f in `cat $LISTFILE`; do
  cat $f >> $RESULTFILE;
done
```